# Js - toggle two div and animate one div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-animate, toggle

I'm working on a mobile menu and I almost complete the code.
Didn't complete yet because there's a small problem in my js:
sometimes, the button that toggle the animation don't change, and it break the menu.

I think it's just a simple toggle order, or ", ; }" missing or in wrong place...

I started learning js this week, I've been in the past 4 hours trying to solve by myself, but no succes. Can you guys help me out ?!
here's the code and [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bv13uatu/5/).

• HTML

```
<div id="mobilecabecalho">SITE TITLE</div>
<div id="mobilebotao-x">✖</div>
<div id="mobilebotao">☰</div>

<div id="mobilemenu">

      - INÍCIO     </br>    
      - PORTIFÓLIO </br>
      - ORÇAMENTO  </br>
      - QUEM SOMOS
```

• CSS

```
html, body{
   margin:0px;
   width:100%;
}

#mobilecabecalho{
    height:72px;
    width:100%;
    background:#B6212D;
    position:fixed;
    z-index:-1;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:72px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:times+new+roman;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing:5px;
    font-size:42px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}


#mobilemenu {
    position:absolute;
    left:100px;
    background:#177F75;
    width:122px;    
    height:102px;
    top:72px;
    font-family:helvetica;
    line-height:25px;
    padding:10px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-radius:0px 0px 10px 0px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}


#mobilebotao{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:2;
    height:72px;
    width:72px;
    background:#B6212D;
    line-height:72px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:helvetica;
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

#mobilebotao-x{
    position:fixed;
    z-index:3;
    height:72px;
    width:72px;
    background:#B6212D;
    line-height:72px;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family:helvetica;
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
```

• JS

```
$("#mobilemenu").css({"left": "-142px",opacity: 0.25})
$( "#mobilebotao-x" ).hide();

$("#mobilebotao").toggle(

    function () { 
        $("#mobilemenu").animate({"left": "0px",opacity: 1,}, 50); 
        $( "#mobilebotao-x" ).show();
    },

    function () { 
    }
);



$("#mobilebotao-x").toggle(

    function () { 
        $("#mobilemenu").animate({"left": "-142px",opacity: 1,}, 50); 
        $("#mobilebotao-x").hide();
    },

    function () { 
        $("#mobilemenu").animate({"left": "0px",opacity: 0.25}, 50);
    }
);
```

I know that maybe there's another easy way to do what I'm trying to do, but, this is "almost" my own code, I want to make it work :)

Comment: now used to this https://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/bv13uatu/6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Now used to click event as like this 
Now you click to your menu and show, animate your code as like this .

```
$("#mobilemenu").css({"left": "-142px",opacity: 0.25})
$( "#mobilebotao-x" ).hide();



$('#mobilebotao').click(function(){
    $( "#mobilebotao-x" ).show();
    $( "#mobilebotao" ).hide();
    $('#mobilemenu').animate({"left": "+0px",opacity: 1}, 50);    
});

$('#mobilebotao-x').click(function(){
    $( "#mobilebotao" ).show();
    $( "#mobilebotao-x" ).hide();
    $('#mobilemenu').animate({"left": "-142",opacity: 0.25}, 50);    
});
```

Now i have created a demo for you check to this **[click here](https://jsfiddle.net/rohitmalikazad/bv13uatu/8/)**

Comment: Aha!
I Should have used "click()" instead of "animate()".
now it make sense for me:
when click -> show button ☰, hide X and animation occurs
when click -> Show button X, hide ☰ and animation occurs
loop process.
perfect, I understood!

Thank you very much!